# exim Timing Out to Gmail

Tags: centos, timeout, exim

I have a Centos server with exim installed. I am trying to send en email from the command line like this:

> exim -v account@gmail.com
>   From: email@mydomain.com
>   To: account@gmail.com
>   Subject: test email
>   this is a test
>
> ^D

I have also tried:

> echo 'test message' | mail -s Test1 account@gmail.com

as well as sending from a PHP script.

The result is the email times out. The logs indicate exim is timing out:

> H=alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [173.194.219.26] Connection timed out

I believe iptables are correct. I have scanned the server from an external IP and ports 25, 265 and 587 are open. (Not sure 587 needs to be since this will be a send-only situation most likely.)

I have also telnet'd to port 25 successfully. (Most of the successful resolutions I have found involved port 25 being blocked. I don't think that is the case here. I have also called my provider and checked. They claim port 25 connections are not blocked.)

I would appreciate some ideas.

Thank you.

Comment: You used telnet to connect to port 25 of what server?  Your server? Your provider's SMTP smarthost?  alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com?  A host returned from `dig mx gmail.com`? That last one -- the MX record host -- is what you should be testing, unless your ISP provides an SMTP server for you to relay through.

Comment: I used telnet to connect to my server (the one exim is running on) to make sure port 25 was open. It is. I am trying to send mail from that server so I am not even sure I need port 25 open but it is. I just checked the MX record and it is '@' which I believe means it should be the same IP as the server which is correct. (I apologize if I am getting the terminology wrong here.)

Comment: It's the google server (173.194.219.26 25) that's timing out, so try: `telnet 173.194.219.26 25`

Comment: I can telnet to 173.194.219.26 port 25 and successfully connect. I am not sure the correct commands to issue. If I send HELO it disconnects.

Comment: you can find an example SMTP dialog here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol. HELO must be followed by the senders domain name.

Comment: you should investigate why you can telnet to 173.194.219.26, yet exim times out. are you both connecting on port 25? If you are using SELINUX, try temporarily disabling it with "setenforce 0" and have exim attempt to send to gmail.com again

Comment: Jim U, you are probably on the right track here. I cannot telnet to any port 25 but I can telnet to port 22 for example. (I know that's SSH, but I at least get a connection and then an error about incorrect protocol.) Perhaps this is an iptables issue?

Comment: I'm not talking about connecting to your server on any port.  I'm talking about the message you reported `H=alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [173.194.219.26] Connection timed out`.  That's a big problem; exim cannot connect to gmail's mail exchanger (mx). Not cool.  However, you said you *can* telnet to that very same host on port 25.  So telnet works, but exim doesn't. Why?  That's where I would look next.  Could be an issue with SELINUX, or maybe exim configured to use a port other than 25 (which would be weird)

Comment: Jim U, I found the issue. Thanks for your help. (I'd mark your comment as the correct answer if I could.) The problem ended up being my provider decided that all mail needs to go through their relay. They didn't tell me about the change and denied doing it when I called. It wasn't until I had eliminated all other possibilities and then called back and got someone better on the phone that they told me and gave me the forwarding server. Thanks again!